# Arranging points

Tags: geometry, slope

How to arrange $n$ points to make sure that they determine an odd number of slopes?

I was thinking to break this into the case where $n$ is even and odd.
If $n$ is even then we put a line through $n-2$ points (with different slopes) and for the last two we put a line through both, since for two points there is always a line going through them.

If $n$ is odd, just take a line through each of these (with different slopes) to get an odd number of slopes.

Am I in the right path? Is this correct?

Comment: So a line only needs to pass through one of the points? Then any arrangement is possible, barring coincident points.

Comment: @Jens I am not sure what the exercise wants... this was my idea

Comment: Is the first sentence all that is known? That leaves a lot of wiggle room.

Comment: @Jens I was working on the number of slopes that $n$ points determine, and a theorem says $n-1$ for odd $n$, and $n$ for even. So I guess the minimum nr is required?

Comment: @Jens I figured out that looking at edges of graph $K_6$ it has $15$ slopes if embedded properly, and each two points share a line. I think this should be the requirement